# how to hide/unhide on facebook posts and comments

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, hide, visible

My question is: How can I hide posts and comments using Facebook SDK in C# ?

and I tried this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
```

```
client.Delete("postId/hidden");
client.Post("postId/hidden");
```

or:

```
client.Delete("postId", new { is_visible = true });
client.Post("postId", new { is_visible = true });
```

but both of them don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, the Facebook API only allows to delete/hide the user's posts not friends nor other feeds